# List of countries and cities to be used in Facebook Graph API for targeting

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I am looking for a list of countries/states/cities that can be used with Facebook Graph API when publishing targeted posts.

I found one JSON file available on [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/ads.getAutoCompleteData/) page but the file doesn't parse correctly and I also doubt whether it can be used for post targeting since the file is for advertisements.

Also, I am not sure whether the third party data like the one [provided](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities) by MaxMind can be used directly with Facebook API.

Does anyone have such a list or can atleast point me to a right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I was able to use the same JSON file I [mentioned](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/ads.getAutoCompleteData/) in my question. As I said in my response to @offbysome, previously I had saved the file by opening it in Google Chrome. But then I used Firefox and used the Right Click => Save File As option to save the file on disk. This file is actually a tar gz (which facebook wrongly names as .php file). After unzipping the file, I was able to use the same code posted in my comment to get the PHP array which I then imported to MySQL.

Comment: this one needs an account id for ADs, how did you get around it? I want to use the list in page targeting

Answer (score 9):

The answer is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/

Comment: thanks for answering ... your answers will get more upvotes if you provide some context for the link.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: except that.... as per usual for facebook docs, the information here seems to be utterly false. specifying anything other than location_types: '["country"]' returns zero results, no matter the query.

Answer (score 6):

To check what countries are available you could just get a response from this endpoint:

URL:
`https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=['country']`

HTTP_METHOD: GET

You also have to set your access token in the URL.

To just see the fields key and name and a larger quantity of countries without being paginated this would be the complete URL:

`https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=['country']&fields=key,name&limit=1000`

Answer (score 1):

For countries: search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=['countries']&limit=1000

For regions: search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=['region']&limit=1000&country_code=PT

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for countries you could always check the [Facebook Internationalization Document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this list will be useful for Post targeting by Country/City. Have you ever tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

The [file](https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/autocomplete_data.php) Facebook publishes seems valid for city/state/country lookups.  It provides the graph id you will need.  And it seems to parse as valid json for me.

Comment: That's strange! If the file is parsing correctly for you can you provide the **actual** code snippet here. That would help me immensely.

Comment: Did you download it to a text file and load it?  If you download it programmatically with code, make sure to set a valid user agent or it won't return the proper info.

Comment: I opened it in Google Chrome and then used **Save as** to save it. And then simply wrote $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('autocomplete_data.txt')); but it returns a null value.