# How to get all cities for specific country from facebook api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook has its own definition of a city, so how can I get list of all places it considers cities. By state or country.

Answer (score 0):

See the second answer: [List of countries and cities to be used in Facebook Graph API for targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227498/list-of-countries-and-cities-to-be-used-in-facebook-graph-api-for-targeting)

```
To check what countries are available you could just get a response from this endpoint:

URL: https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=['country']

HTTP_METHOD: GET

You also have to set your access token in the URL.

To just see the fields key and name and a larger quantity of countries without being paginated this would be the complete URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=['country']&fields=key,name&limit=1000
```

Thank you very much!